# How to make control in controltemplate visible only when treeview has items bound to it

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, treeview, controltemplate

So I have this control template, and I want the signalnamepanel (just a label for time, and i'm going to add an x axis beside it) to only become visible when items are bound to the Treeview.

Otherwise it will look weird because the namepanel will be floating there by itself.  I am guessing I need to use triggers of some kind, but I'm not sure what I would trigger off of.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TreeView}" TargetType="TreeView">
      <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
      <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
      <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
      <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeView">

              <ScrollViewer 
                Focusable="False"
                CanContentScroll="False"
                Padding="4">
                <StackPanel>
                  <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="19" />
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=signal_graph_window_width, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <wpfExp:SignalNamePanel Grid.Column="1"
                      Height="{Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=GraphHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
                      MainText="Time" 
                    />
                    <wpfExp:SignalGraphAxis Grid.Column="2"
                      Height="{Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=GraphHeight, Mode=OneWay}"                
                      PenWidth="{Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=GraphPenWidth, Mode=OneWay}"
                      X_Scale="{Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=X_Scale, Mode=OneWay}"
                      MaxTimeValue="{Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=_SignalDataViewModel.MaxTimeValue, Mode=OneWay}"
                    />
                  </Grid>

                  <ItemsPresenter/>
                </StackPanel>
              </ScrollViewer>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                   Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                      Property="Stroke"
                                      Value="#FF1BBBFA"/>
                <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                      Property="Fill"
                                      Value="Transparent"/>
              </Trigger>
              </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: `<Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="True">
<Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="YourControl" Value="Visible"/>
</Trigger>` - it you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi You can use HasItems in Trigger like.

```
XAML:
<Trigger Property="ItemsControl.HasItems" Value="True">
 <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Name" Value="Collapsed"/>

</Trigger>
```